# “GNU GRUB version 2.06” on early 2009 iMac

Tags: macos, windows

I tried to install 32‑bit Windows 7 on my early 2009 iMac, but I had Linux on it before. I tried to delete my partition and make a new one, but I had the GPT partition, so it didn’t let me use it anyway.
So, I tried to put in an OS X USB and boot to it, but now I just can’t get the boot menu.
Anyone know how to fix it?
(I had Zorin OS lite)

Comment: I tested using a 32‑bit Windows 7 with SP1 from [here](https://archive.org/details/win-7-pro-32-64-iso) in a virtual machine. I deleted all partitions shown on the display titled "Where do you want to install Windows?", then selected "New" and created partitions. The GPT partitioning was replaced by MBR partitioning.

Comment: I deleted one of the drives and selected “new”. The reason I didn’t delete the other is because I thought it was the recovery drive and had 512 MB. I would love to boot back into the dvd or the macos usb, but I can’t even do that anymore
edit: for more context, I can’t boot into the usb because when I try to go to the boot menu i just keep getting the gnu grub thing

Comment: I am confused by what you have posted so far. Let me try some simple questions. Can you boot from the Windows DVD? If so, can you reach the display titled "Where do you want to install Windows?".

Comment: I can’t get to boot from the windows dvd since I can’t actually get to the startup/boot menu. And when it gets to the GNU grub screen, the dvd just ejects.

Comment: Also, when I tried to erase it the first time, it still said windows can’t use it because it’s gpt

Comment: I used my 2011 iMac to burn my 32-bit Windows 7 SP1 ISO file to a RW DVD. I started my 2007 iMac, immediately inserted the DVD and held down the alt/option key until the Mac Startup Manager icons appeared. The icon representing the DVD was a DVD image with the label `Windows`. I selected to boot from the DVD and was successful. If this does not work for you, then either the DVD, optical drive or some other hardware is defective. You might be better off trying other method I gave as my answer to your previous question.

Comment: I can’t get to the startup manager though.

Comment: Then either the DVD, optical drive or some other hardware is defective.

Comment: maybe that’s the case. but if it was, it would be really weird because I could get to the startup manager just fine before I wiped the hard drive

Comment: You have not wiped the HDD. If you did, then you could not boot to grub. The Mac Startup Manager is not on the HDD. The Mac Startup Manager is implemented in the firmware and would be very difficult to erase. I have used third party keyboards with my 2007 iMac, where the alt key was not recognized at startup. This caused me not to be able to reach the Mac Startup Manager. Sometimes the problem can be something simple.

Comment: yeah maybe it’s just the keyboard, thanks for your help

Comment: I fixed the issue, i just had to put the dvd in before turning the mac on, and then getting to the startup manager

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, i just had to put the dvd in before turning the mac on, and then getting to the startup manager